# Automatically "attach to Process" for a service debug

Tags: delphi, service, process

I'm currently create a service and I need to debug them. I use also the "Attach to processes" form.

(As described on first paragraph http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Debugging_Service_Applications )

But it's possible to auto associate the debugger with the service after build them ?

I use already the pre-build events for restart my service.

Comment: If you built your service correctly, it should start a thread on service start. Make a simple console application that does the same thing (ie starting the thread) and debug the console application...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it's possible to auto associate the debugger with the service after build them ?

No it is not.  The debugger cannot launch a service executable directly, only the SCM can do that.  Although the SCM can be scripted to launch a service programmably, such as from a command line batch file, the debugger cannot be attached to a running process programmably, only manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a normal application that does the same as the service to debug your code. Just add all needed units to a second project. We use this approach to debug our services (additionally this application contains a logfile viewer where we can watch the logs that our service produces live)

Antother approach ist the following:

- Create a "markerfile" somewhere (just a simple textfile)
- Inside the service there is a loop that exits when the marker file does not exist
- Set a breakpoint just after the waiting loop
- Start the service (it loops waiting forthe markerfile to be deleted
- Attach the debugger to the service process
- Delete the "markerfile"
- The service exits the waiting loop and stops at your breakpoint
- Debug